# Assigning Single Firebase Data to Global Variable swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, variables

I am trying to assign the output of a single firebase data to a global variable. However, I am unable to do so. How do I resolve this ?

```
 let ref = Database.database().reference()
 var GPSlatdata : Double!
 ref.child("GPSData/devices/1/latitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let latitudefire = snapshot.value as? Double
       {
        self.latLabel.text = "\(latitudefire)"

        //output, now assigning to global variable for other use

        GPSlatdata = latitudefire

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: There isn't a error, its just the method that I am doing, I am unable to extract the single data from ref.child and assign it to the established global variable.

Comment: Does your label text get set?

Comment: Yes, I tested to see if both my label is getting the output's as a check and it is doing that. However I am still unable to pass it into the global variable.

Comment: When you say you *can't pass it*, what does that mean? Did you try adding *print(latitudeFire)* within the closure to ensure you're actually getting valid data? Are you attempting to do something with the GPSlatdata vars before the closure completes? Remember that Firebase is asynchronous so you can use GPSlatdata until it's populated within the closure. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)